# Grab a person's Facebook profile picture and embed it

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

When you embed a "like this page" button on your page, your profile picture and other people's profile pictures are shown. This requires no authentication, because it's all done through an iframe.

I want to place a placeholder on my site, but I want to spice it up, by adding their profile picture from Facebook instead. Obviously it would have to be in an iframe, because I don't want people to accept terms and stuff like that.

Is this doable? All I have seen requires their user id and so on, which I won't be able to get, as I technically don't handle any of their requests (it's all done client-side because of an iframe). Thanks.

Comment: you want an iframe in your page that shows a visitors facebook profile picture - what if they don't have a (I know this may sound shocking, so brace yourself) facebook account?

Comment: @JaromandaX Good question. You can grab the contents of an iframe using `.contents()` with jQuery. With that, you should be able to determine whether or not the profile picture is simply there or a placeholder Facebook placed.

Comment: `You can grab the contents of an iframe using .contents()` - that's where you are (thankfully) wrong - your page has **zero** access to a cross origin iframe - those wild days of the internet are **long gone**

Comment: you can only do that by authorizing the user. you only get the (app scoped) user id after authorizing - for very good reasons, because the user should stay anonymous for you.

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah yeah that's right. I completely forgot. Maybe Facebook just puts a placeholder. In which case, I can just embed it without even checking.

Comment: @luschn That's the beauty of iframes. By embedding the iframe on the page (to the correct Facebook page like /my/profile-picture/ (which won't work)), I won't ever know who tried to access the site.

Comment: yes, but there is no iframe (social plugin) for this.

Comment: @luschn That's unfortunate. I guess I'll have to place a placeholder profile image then :(